# MySql: Slow join and group by on indexed columns

Tags: mysql, index, performance, query-performance

The following query takes 15-20s to run

```
SELECT "Trade_US"."ID" AS "Trade_US.ID",
"Server_US"."Name" AS "Server_US.Name",
"Trade_US"."TradeTypeID" AS "Trade_US.TradeTypeID",
"Users"."ID" AS "Users.ID",
"Users"."NickName" AS "Users.NickName",
"Item"."ID" AS "Item.ID",
"Item"."ItemTypeID" AS "Item.ItemTypeID",
"Item"."ItemQualityID" AS "Item.ItemQualityID",
"Item"."Level" AS "Item.Level",
"Item"."IconURL" AS "Item.IconURL",
"Trade_US"."Amount" AS "Trade_US.Amount",
"Trade_US"."BonusPercent" AS "Trade_US.BonusPercent",
"Trade_US"."StartBidTotalSilver" AS "Trade_US.StartBidTotalSilver",
"Trade_US"."BuyOutTotalSilver" AS "Trade_US.BuyOutTotalSilver",
"Trade_US"."Description" AS "Trade_US.Description",
"Trade_US"."LastUpdate" AS "Trade_US.LastUpdate",
"Trade_US"."LastBump" AS "Trade_US.LastBump",
CONCAT(COALESCE("ItemPrefix_Text_EN"."PrefixName",""),"Item_Text_EN"."ItemName") AS "FullItemName",
MAX("TradeOffer_US"."PriceTotalSilver") AS "BestOfferTotalSilver" 
FROM "Trade_US" 
  Inner JOIN "Users" ON (("Trade_US"."TraderUserID" = "Users"."ID"))
  Inner JOIN "Item" ON (("Trade_US"."ItemID" = "Item"."ID"))
  Inner JOIN "Item_Text_EN" ON (("Item"."ID" = "Item_Text_EN"."ItemID"))
  Inner JOIN "Server_US" ON (("Server_US"."ID" = "Trade_US"."GameServerID"))
  Left JOIN "ItemPrefix_Text_EN" ON (("ItemPrefix_Text_EN"."ItemPrefixID" = "Trade_US"."ItemPrefixID"))
  Left JOIN "TradeReply_US" ON (("TradeReply_US"."TradeID" = "Trade_US"."ID"))
  Left JOIN "TradeOffer_US" ON (("TradeOffer_US"."ReplyID" = "TradeReply_US"."ID"))
 GROUP BY "Trade_US"."ID"
 ORDER BY "Trade_US"."LastBump" desc LIMIT 300000, 10
```

Explain gives the following result
[image]

Here are the table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    ID int primary key,

    NickName nvarchar(50) unique not null
);/*2 rows*/

CREATE TABLE ItemType(
    ID INT primary key,
    Name varchar(50) not null
);/*80 rows*/

CREATE TABLE ItemQuality(
    ID INT primary key,
    Name varchar(50) not null
);/*6 rows*/

CREATE TABLE Item(
    ID INT   primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ItemTypeID int not null,
    `Level` int not null,
    ItemQualityID int not null,
    IconURL varchar(100) not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (ItemTypeID) REFERENCES ItemType(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemQualityID) REFERENCES ItemQuality(ID)
);/*5k rows*/
CREATE INDEX Level ON Item(Level);

CREATE TABLE Item_Text_EN(
    ItemID int primary key,
    ItemName varchar(50) not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFERENCES Item (ID)
);/*5k rows*/
CREATE INDEX ItemName ON Item_Text_EN(ItemName);

CREATE TABLE ItemPrefix(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PrefixTypeID INT not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (PrefixTypeID) REFERENCES ItemPrefixType(ID)
);/*100 rows*/

CREATE TABLE ItemPrefix_Text_EN(
    ItemPrefixID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PrefixName nvarchar(50) not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (ItemPrefixID) REFERENCES ItemPrefix(ID)
);/*100 rows*/

CREATE TABLE Trade_US(
    ID INT primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    GameServerID int not null,
    TradeTypeID int not null,
    TraderUserID int not null,
    ItemID int not null,
    Amount int not null,
    BonusPercent int null,
    ItemPrefixID INT null,
    StartBidTotalSilver int null,
    BuyOutTotalSilver int not null,

    `Description` nvarchar(200) null,
    LastUpdate datetime not null,
    LastBump datetime not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (GameServerID) REFERENCES Server_US(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TradeTypeID) REFERENCES TradeType(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TraderUserID) REFERENCES Users(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemPrefixID) REFERENCES ItemPrefix(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFERENCES Item(ID),

    CHECK (BonusPercent >=0 ),
    CHECK (Amount > 0 AND Amount < 99999),
    CHECK (StartBidTotalSilver < 100000000 AND StartBidTotalSilver >= 0),
    CHECK (BuyOutTotalSilver < 100000000 AND BuyOutTotalSilver >= 0)
);/*1million duplicated rows*/
CREATE INDEX BonusPercent ON Trade_US (BonusPercent);
CREATE INDEX StartBidTotalSilver ON Trade_US (StartBidTotalSilver);
CREATE INDEX BuyOutTotalSilver ON Trade_US (BuyOutTotalSilver);
CREATE INDEX LastBump ON Trade_US (LastBump);

CREATE TABLE TradeReply_US(
    ID INT primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TradeID int not null,
    ReplyUserID int not null,
    `Message` nvarchar(200) null,
    `Time` datetime not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (ReplyUserID) REFERENCES Users(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TradeID) REFERENCES Trade_US (ID) on delete cascade
);/*5 rows*/

CREATE TABLE TradeOffer_US(
    ReplyID int primary key,
    PriceTotalSilver int not null,

    FOREIGN KEY (ReplyID) REFERENCES TradeReply_US (ID) on delete cascade,
    CHECK (PriceTotalSilver < 100000000 AND PriceTotalSilver >= 0)
);/*2 rows*/

CREATE TABLE Server_US(
    ID INT primary key,
    Name varchar(20) not null
);/*3 rows*/
```

Profiling result:

```
17 Init 61 µs 
18 Optimizing 14 µs 
19 Statistics 158 µs 
20 Preparing 41 µs 
21 Creating Tmp Table 165 µs 
22 Executing 2 µs 
23 Copying To Tmp Table 14.2 s 
24 Sorting Result 972.5 ms 
25 Sending Data 1.1 s 
26 End 5 µs
```

*Any column named as ID is a primary key
*Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503
*Right now it doesnt have a where clause, but the user might choose to do a search which results in any combination of indexed columns being included in the where clause.

I have tried to remove all the group by clause + max(...) and it takes around 8 sec to run. I used force index on LastBump column with it and it will take around 6 sec to run still which is unreasonably long considering all columns are indexed and it only has 1m rows of data. I tried adding compsite index on all the columns in Trade_US which will be used to join and it doesnt help at all. I wiped the entire database and then recreated all the tables to see if it is the problem of high index fragmentation but still no luck. Totally out of ideas.. any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are more likely to attract good answers if you include DDL for the missing tables *Server_US* and *ItemPrefix_Text* at least. Please use ANSI standard double quotes instead of apostrophes. In the absence of an index `MAX("TradeOffer_US"."PriceTotalSilver")`, Perforce will have to scan all rows of the intermediate result set. You should try using a subquery to perform this scan on the minimal set instead. You also appear to have unreferenced tables in your JOIN list. Finally, the `GROUP BY` column list should match your `SELECT` list, for easy comparison.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens idk what you mean by unreferenced tables. Users is referenced by TraderUserID, Item is referenced by ItemID, Item_Text_EN is referenced by Item (which i need the name of the item) Server_US is referenced by GameServerID, ItemPrefix_Text_EN is referenced by ItemPrefixID, TradeReply_US references Trade_US.ID, and TradeOffer_US references TradeReply_US.ID. Everything else is fixed but still no luck

Comment: @PieterGeerkens seems like i only need to group by Trade_US.ID to get my result. Removed the redundant Group bys and updated. But still takes 16 sec to run

Comment: Mysql optimizer should put the table with the least rows first,can you change the JOIN order,put Trade_US last in the INNER JOIN sequence or force the table order with STRAIGHT_JOIN.

Comment: @Mihai now it runs even slower...